# Kaltura ad not clickable on iOS in fullscreen

Tags: ios, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, angular-ui-bootstrap, kaltura

I'm developing an AngularJS SPA which displays videos hosted on Kaltura via dynamic embed:

```
window.kWidget.embed({
            "targetId": kalturaContainerId,
            "wid": "_"+$scope.kalturaPartnerId,
            "uiconf_id": $scope.kalturaUiconfigId,
            "flashvars":  {
                    "streamerType": "auto",
                    "disableHLSOnJs": "true",
                    "autoPlay": true,
                    "EmbedPlayer.EnableIpadHTMLControls" : false
            },
            "cache_st": Math.random(),
            "entry_id": $scope.video.kalturaEntryId
    });
```

I switched to `"EmbedPlayer.EnableIpadHTMLControls" : false` because I didn't get the fullscreen functionality working for a video displayed in a Bootstrap Modal on iPad.

With this configuration, I'm facing the problem, that my ads aren't clickable on iOS in fullscreen mode. If the video/advertisement is running "embedded" in the HTML page, the clickthrough is working, and the correct page is opened in a new browser tab. If the video runs in fullscreen mode, nothing happens on click...

Does anyone have any guess for me, maybe a parameter from http://player.kaltura.com/docs/api which I missed?